# How to integrate 3rd party SDKs into Smartface App Studio?

Tags: smartface.io

Is there any way to integrate 3rd party SDKs into my app which built with Smartface App Studio. 
If so, this feature helps me to integrate crash reporting SDKs, notification SDKs, etc.,

Please provide any necessary info or links to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it's not supported yet

Answer (score 0):

New release of Smartface(450), lets you to use plugins. You can download it from https://account.smartface.io/Account/Register

You can check these documents about developing smartface plugins:
http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/plugins/developing-smartface-plugins/

For Android: http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/plugins/developing-android-plugin/

For iOS: http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/plugins/developing-ios-plugin/

Also, you can check the helloworld plugin examples for both iOS and Android:
http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/plugins/hello-world-with-android-plugin/
http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/plugins/hello-world-with-ios-plugin/

Comment: Will this feature useful for me to integrate 3rd party SDKs like crashlytics, etc.,
Means, i can integrate those SDKs into my android project by android studio and build plug-in and config in smartface app studio. Right?

Comment: Yes, you can develop any plugin in native and use it in smartface. This is a new feature.

Comment: Thanks. Will try with this then.